# Homework problem about creating random lists with evens and odds separated

Tags: python, algorithm

1. Ask user for a limit of random numbers. Make a list of 15 random integers from 0 to the user’s limit.
2. Place odd and even numbers into two lists. Print both lists and the greatest value in both.
3. Hint: x % y returns the remainder of division. If x%2==0, the number is even.
   Check the user’s input. If the input is not a positive integer, ask for a new one.

I tried to import random and ask for a list range of 0 to users input of 15 numbers but I can't seem to get code to work with input on the other defining factor

```
from random import randint
i=int(input('Type the limit:  '))
numbers=[]

for i in range(15):
    n=randint(0,??)
    numbers.append(n)
    print(numbers)
```

Comment: Can you describe exactly what the program is doing that you didn't expect, and explain what you expected instead?

Comment: You are using the same variable name (`i`) for your input number and range.

Comment: Note: "**from** 0", then you shouldn't start at `randint(1, ...)`

Comment: @glibdud I'm trying to get the first part of the question done and keep getting errors if I don't put any number in position of the question marks

Comment: @GaryKerr the problem is I don't know what to put in for the variable

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging  and reading the documentation of [random.randint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)  is all you need beside the tips you already have. Did you use/consult either one?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I haven't yet but I will now! Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution using numpy: (i dont understant your third part)

```
import numpy as np
userlimit = int(input('Type the limit:  '))
list1 = np.random.randint(0, userlimit + 1, 15)
oddlist = [x for x in list1 if x%2!=0]
evenlist = [x for x in list1 if x%2==0]
print(f'event list: {evenlist} ')
print(f'length of evenlist:{len(evenlist)}, its max number = {max(evenlist)}')
print(f'odd list: {oddlist} ')
print(f'length of oddlist:{len(oddlist)}, its max number = {max(oddlist)}')
```

output:

```
Type the limit:  >? 10
event list: [6, 4, 4, 6, 8] 
length of evenlist:5, its max number = 8
odd list: [1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 5, 3, 1, 7, 1] 
length of oddlist:10, its max number = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems in your code, but you were on the right path.

First, as mentioned above, you will want to use a different variable in the loop other than i, since you want to preserve the limit that the user gives you.

Second, you want to start at 0 and end at the user input, so randint() should be from 0 to the user input.

```
for j in range(15):
    n = randint(0,i)
```

Third, in order to tell if a number is even or odd, the hint tells you what to do. n % 2 means that if you divide a number by two, n % 2 would be its remainder. If n % 2 == 0, put it in an even number array. If not, put it in an odd number array.

Finally, in order to keep track of the maximum number, simply initialize a number (greatestVal) to zero, and, in the loop, check if the randomly generated number is greater than greatestVal.

The code is as follows, but please understand where the changes are coming from.

```
from random import randint
i=int(input('Type the limit:  '))
oddNumbers=[]
evenNumbers = []
greatestNumb = 0;

for j in range(15):
    n=randint(0,i)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        evenNumbers.append(n)
    else:
        oddNumbers.append(n)

    if n > greatestNumb:
        greatestNumb = n
print(oddNumbers)
print(evenNumbers)
print(greatestNumb)
```

Edit : Some grammatical errors